# Iron Router - Routers no longer working (v1.3)

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I thought I had iron router nailed but for some reason I'm running into issues with it not displaying additional views beyond the root default template - and it used to work fine.

Basically I have a default layout template for the main view. Then I have a dynamic route that essentially displays different user lists.

you can see this here:

placelist.meteorapp.com - main

placelist.meteorapp.com/cmeelater - dynamic user lists

The main view is totally fine (has a logged in and logged out state) but the template for the dynamic sub routes (/name-of-list) isn't displaying - instead it's displaying the default template.

It was working before but now I'm a slightly lost. Any help would be super appreciated. (I've poked around for info).

Additonal info:

What's happening below in my **route.js** is a session variable gets passed to a query from the URL parameter. This then pulls the lists for that users based on the URL param and should use "userListsShared" template to display this (btw this works if I just blindly insert {{> userListsShared}} into the main template but I don't want that).

I thought if you declared the template to use in the route it would use that template - is there some inheritance thing going on?

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'userListsShared',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    waitOn: function() { 
      return Meteor.subscribe('posts'); 
      return Meteor.subscribe('userposts');
    }
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.route('main', {
              path: '/',
              template: 'main'
            }
      );
    this.route('shared', {
      path: '/:sharelink',
      template:'userListsShared',
      data: function () 
              {
                   Session.set('curShareList', this.params.sharelink);
              }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Router.map` is deprecated in Iron Router. You should be using `Router.route` to define each route now. Also, don't use the `data` method to set session variables. That method is for defining the page context, and expects to return an object. Use the `onBeforeAction` method, like this:

```
// If the route name and template are the same, you can just specify the name.
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'main'
})

Router.route('/:sharelink', function () {
  name: 'shared',
  template: 'userListsShared'
})

// The 'only' property is a list of what routes the function will be called before.
Router.onBeforeAction(
  function () {
    Session.set('curShareList', this.params.sharelink);
  },
  only: ['shared'] // You could also use "except: ['main']" instead
});
```

Check out the official guide; it walks you through the process: http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/

Comment: Hi, ok so the below seems to be the final fix. Using except seemed to do the job of "use this default layout except in this case" kind of thing. Anyway, thanks for pointing me in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'main',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    waitOn: function() { 
      return Meteor.subscribe('posts'); 
      return Meteor.subscribe('userposts');
    }
});


Router.route('/', function () {
    this.layout('main');
    this.render('main');
    except:['userListsShared']
});

Router.route('/:sharelink', function () {
    this.layout('userListsShared');
    this.render('userListsShared');
    var thisuserlist = this.params.sharelink;
   //var routeName = Router.current().route.getName();
   //console.log("routeName = " + routeName);
  Session.set('curShareList', this.params.sharelink);
});
```